# Use a delimiter (Java)?

Tags: java, delimiter

I want to traverse an ArrayList of Strings and determine if each one is an operator (+, -, /, *, %).  Do you use a delimiter?  If so, how would you use it in this case.

Comment: *As is* your question is not clear, you should rephrase

Comment: Suppose I have ArrayList<String> list = {"12", "510", "+", "2", "*"}.  I want to separate the operators from the operands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way of checking is to simply have the known delimiters in a list, and check each item to see if it's present in that list. e.g.:

```
List<String> delimiters = new ArrayList<>();
delimiters.add("+");
delimiters.add("-");
delimiters.add("/");
delimiters.add("*");
delimiters.add("%");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");
list.add("+");
list.add("-");
list.add("/");
list.add("*");
list.add("%");

for (String s : list)
{
    if (delimiters.contains(s))
    {
        System.out.println("This is a delimiter. " + s);
    }
}
```

Edit for the example in the comments:

```
List<String> delimiters = new ArrayList<>();
delimiters.add("+");
delimiters.add("-");
delimiters.add("/");
delimiters.add("*");
delimiters.add("%");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("12");
list.add("510");
list.add("+");
list.add("2");
list.add("*");

List<String> operators = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> operands = new ArrayList<>();

for (String s : list)
{
    if (delimiters.contains(s))
    {
        operators.add(s);
    }
    else
    {
        operands.add(s);
    }
}
System.out.println("Operators: " + operators);
System.out.println("Operands: " + operands);
```

Output:

```
Operators: [+, *]
Operands: [12, 510, 2]
```

Comment: If you want to check for presence, use a Set (or a Map) instead of a List.

Comment: @DavidConrad I agree that an ArrayList is not the best, performance-wise - but it works.